# JSP - How to call Servlet only after Action finishes executing?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

Ok, I have a JSP,a Servlet and an Action class. JSP has a "Download" button which on click calls 2 functions - "build()" and "download()". "build()" function executes an action. The Action creates and builds the file on the server. "download()" is used to get the file from the server using the servlet so the user can download it.

```
  Action.java
    -----------
    buildFile() { 
    //build file/writes in the file
    }

    Servlet.java
    -----------
    doget(){
    //gets the file from the server
    }

    JSP
    ---
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function build() {
    //calls buildFile();
    //form.submit();
}

function download() {
window.open('/Servlet');
}
</script>

<input type="button" class="button" value="Download" onclick="build();download();"/>
```

Now the problem is, whenever I click on "Download", download() is being called IMMEDIATELY after build(). So if the file has less data, then the building process is completed and user is able to download the file. But if the data being written to the file is large, download() is still being called IMMEDIATELY after "build()" and the user gets only partial data in his downloaded file(cause the file is still being built behind the scene). I want to do something which will make the download() to wait till the Action(buildFile()) has completed executing. Also, without the form.submit() the action is not being called for some reason. That's why I can't make use of "document.ready" or "window.onLoad". So please suggest something else. I have also tried this:

```
function build() {
        //calls buildFile();
        //form.submit();
download();
    }

    function download() {
    window.open('/Servlet');
    }
<input type="button" class="button" value="Download" onclick="build();"/>
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just call build() and then at the end of my build method in action class, I call the doget() method in servlet.

```
 Action.java
    -----------
    buildFile() { 
    //build file/writes in the file
      Servlet servlet = new Servlet();
      servlet.doget();
    }

    Servlet.java
    -----------
    doget(){
    //gets the file from the server
    }  

<input type="button" class="button" value="Download" onclick="build();"/>
```

This builds my file, no matter how long it takes, then pops up the download box to the user.

Comment: This is no different than just doing everything in one servlet, which is more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling two javascript methods build() and download() right after each other, just use a straight HTML form to submit to a servlet that both builds and downloads the file.

```
 <form action='/Servlet' method='post' target='_blank'>
   <input type='hidden' name='param_needed_to_build_file' value='something' />
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Download" />
 </form>
```

target='_blank' causes it to open a new window. You could also use method='get' if you want.  You could also still use javascript to popup the servlet in another window if you want, but the building and downloading should both be in the servlet.

In your servlet, implement the doGet and/or doPost methods to call the Java functions build() and download() both of which will be in your servlet.  Or you could put the build() method in another class referenced and utilized in your servlet.

In fact, normal practice would be to build the file and write it out to the response object directly rather than to the filesystem first and then read it (unless you want to save the file for later for some reason).

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that solution, but is there a way to solve this problem without asking the Servlet to build the file?

Comment: What would be the point? You still have to wait for the file to be built either way. Unless you send an Ajax request to one servlet to build the file, wait for the response back, then write a link to the next servlet that retrieves the file.

Answer (score -1):

Your button kind of says it all. You want the user to press the Download-button and get the file. But before the file can be fetched it has to be constructed.

This tells you that you need to do two things; build and then download.

```
onclick="buildAndDownload();"

function buildAndDownload(){
    // build file
    // start the download
 }
```

You could even separate the logic of these two actions into two separate methods.

What you need for your download-function is a way to query the server if the file is ready.

```
function download (){
     while(! fileIsReady()){
           Thread.sleep(500);
       }
       // Start the download
}
```

Of course, if you know that the file always is ready for download after x milliseconds, and don't want to build more serverside functionality, you can just call 'Thread.sleep(1500);' for 1.5seconds wait before starting the download.